# Why is$ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$ when n goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n=e$?

I think it involves $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}=e$ but not sure how to get from one to the other.

Comment: At first we need how you did define $e$, because often $e$ is defined as this limit

Comment: well before the taylor expansion I knew e as ln(1), the limit is the third definition of e that I encountered. EDIT: which is wrong, oops

Comment: $e$ is not $\ln(1)$. $\ln(1) = 0$. You probably meant $e$ is the unique real number such that $\ln(e) = 1$. But for that to be meaningful it is useful to know how you define the natural log.

Comment: oh darn, you are right

Comment: Similar question posted and deleted 15 hours ago (by different account): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475493/basic-question-on-limit

Comment: the answer to my question is indeed in the possible duplicate. However I must admit I dont understand the answer given there.

Comment: e is often defined this way. since you asked why, the answer depends on the definition of limit.Do you know how to define limit?

What you probably are expecting is not that kind of an answer.

Comment: In the possible duplicate they state $\frac{1}{n^k} {n \choose k} \to \frac{1}{k!}$ as $n \to \infty$, I dont see how this works. Is it in the definition of ${n \choose k} $? For .SE ettiquette: should I delete my question now that it is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @Leo Search the site. There is also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/54357/73025) with several answers, and most probably many more.

Comment: You are right. The answer there explains what I ask in my comment above and is exactly what I was hoping to get here. Should I delete this question?

Comment: I agree with Dominic. The more beautiful approach to introduce the ln is through an integral based upon y = 1/x Based upon this assumption and the limit definition of the derivative on y=1/x, you can derive the limit version of the ln. From here you can dervie the derivative of the exponential function from which the e-power arises. I can't explain it here, but if you read a calc book with this introduction of the ln, your question will be answered very clear.

Comment: Euler original definition of ${\rm e}^{x}$ was to look for a function ${\rm f}\left(x\right)$ which satisfies
${\rm f}'\left(x\right)
 =
 {\rm f}\left(x\right), \forall\ x$. Then, ${\rm f}^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right) = {\rm f}\left(0\right)$. Then, you get ${\rm f}\left(x\right) = {\rm f}\left(0\right)\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x^{n}/n!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried expanding by the binomial theorem? ;-)
$$(1/n+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\frac1{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac1{n^k}$$then as $n\to\infty$ we find $n!/(n^k (n-k)!)\to1$ hence we have:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\cdot n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\equiv e$$

Comment: Why does the limit is $1$ ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{n^k}\to 1$.$

Comment: oops -- did not see that earlier. @Belgi $n!/(n-k)!=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ and so $n!/((n-k)!n^k)=n/n\cdot(n-1)/n\cdots (n-k+1)/n$

Comment: observe $(n-r)/n=1-r/n$ hence as $n\to\infty$ each of our product terms tends to $1$

Comment: @Grobber - thanks!