# Proof for closed form approximation of e

Tags: power-series, closed-form

I am familiar with the derivation of $e$ from a power series,  $e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} $ but have [not found](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html) the proof for 
the following representation in any textbook

$e = \lim_{x\ \to \infty}  (1+ \frac{1}{x})^{x} $

What is the proof or where might I find it?

Comment: As I can recall in the textbook, the `e` is defined first by a limit (1+1/n)^n for n goes to infinity.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39170/73025) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/54357/73025) and ...

Comment: @eccstartup, I think his question is essentially that if $e$ is defined by that series, how you show it is equivalent to the limit definition.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong, I think many textbooks on analysis have the proof of the equivalence.